# How can I use a side panel to access a screen for a vendor?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to add a side panel to the Bills and Adjustments screen which will bring up a vendor record.  When adding the Navigation to the Bills and Adjustments screen, I can't get to the actual Vendor screen, just the GI of the Vendors:

[image]

Any Idea how I can open the Vendor entry screen using the side panel action? Or is this not how it is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Dashboards,reports, or GIs are allowed according to the documentation
[image]